# Duda de semáforos en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, hilos

¿ Que diferencia hay en los semáforos entre usar un 
`.acquire()`y un `.tryAcquire()` ?

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
sem.acquire();
sem.tryAcquire();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la API la diferencia es el comportamiento de los metodos:

**acquire:**

*Acquires a permit from this semaphore, blocking until one is available, or the thread is interrupted.*

**tryAcquire:**

*Acquires a permit from this semaphore, only if one is available at the time of invocation.*

El primero bloquea hasta que el permit este disponible mientras el segundo solo lo adquiere si esta alguno disponible en el momento de la invocacion.

Lee el Javadoc para una mejor referencia: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html